# Rails number_to_currency precision based on size of dollar amount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to set the `precision` attribute on `number_to_currency` based on the dollar amount.

So if the dollar amount is a single digit, show 2 digits. Otherwise, show 0.

Something like: `number_to_currency(123456.51, precision: 2 if < 10)`

Is there a way to do that globally for `number_to_currency` instead of doing some sort of `if/else` for every instance?

Comment: If it just one-off use try number_to_currency(amount, precision: amount < 10.0 ? 2 : 0). Else got with custom helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own helper method which utilizes `number_to_currency` along with your own custom logic.

```
def number_to_currency_with_precision(value)
  precision = value < 10 ? 2 : 0
  number_to_currency(value, precision: precision)
end
```